# Will the operator be unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

$(A:M_{2}->M_{2})$ - multiplying right-side on matrix (1). Is this a unitary operator? Dot product is 
$(A,B) = \sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2}a_{ij}b_{ij}$.

$
\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
13 & 46\\ 
23/2 & 13
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)
$
(1)

And sorry for my English.

Comment: You may want to look at [this link for math formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for ways of improving this and other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not - it is not even an isometry. Prove this by applying your operator to the matrix with all entries equal to $1$.

Comment: Sorry, but determinant of what matrix are you writing about?

Comment: I'm writing about matrix (1).

Comment: But, it`s det is -360.

Comment: Oh, right, silly of me - that's 13 there, not 23. I will edit my answer (but the operator is certainly not unitary either way).